# Develop spelling dictionary and grammar support in macOS for unsupported languages

Tags: spellcheck

I'm coming from Windows and Linux world, so don't be too harsh :-)

Is it possible to develop a spelling dictionary and grammar support for unsupported languages?

Is there any documentation available? After some searching, I didn't find anything useful.

Answer (score 0):

On the topic of spelling, you could start further research at [https://www.cs.hmc.edu/~geoff/ispell.html](https://www.cs.hmc.edu/%7Egeoff/ispell.html).  That will provide you a list of dictionaries for already-supported languages, and a framework for developing  your own.  I'd suggest that *ispell* is fairly well regarded, but is not the only spelling system for macOS/Unix.

As for grammar, a whole other kettle of fish that is.

Comment: Thank you. I'm interested in grammar. Any idea where to start reading?

Comment: Not really, but there is a related Linguistics site which has some material on *computational linguistics* you might start with.

Comment: Tnx. I didn't find anything. Do you have a link? Otherwise, I will ask there from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

MacOS can normally use any dictionary file available for OpenOffice and its relatives. [Here](https://github.com/wooorm/dictionaries) is one source.  These come from [Hunspell](http://hunspell.github.io).